# Can we access Google Person api without signing in through our app in Android?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I want to access the Person's gender and age group via Google People API. Can we fetch the information without getting the user signed in from our app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends interlay upon what they have set to public.   You can use [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) with a public api key.  All you need is the API key from the Google Developer console and the Id of the person in question.

> 110241806600768156114

The Request

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/110241806600768156114?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Response

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/uQPoHyS74SJW3R-WzeaqLgt_EL8\"",
 "gender": "male",
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "110241806600768156114",
 "displayName": "djordje tankosic",
 "name": {
  "familyName": "tankosic",
  "givenName": "djordje"
 },
 "url": "https://plus.google.com/110241806600768156114",
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-XtK8-6zkQHY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAJk/hI2NqHzmNrA/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "circledByCount": 18,
 "verified": false
}
```

This person who I just randomly grabbed there Id off Google+ has gender set to public.  As you can see there is not much other information available to you.

I suggest you go to the bottom of the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) page and do some testing with the try me don't authenticate it.  This will ensure that you are only checking public access.   If you want to see the different authenticate it then use `'me'` in the id field.  This will show you the response for an authenticated user.